# How to extract the weights and bias from tensorflow neural network and how to compute the prediction on your own in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm using tensorflow in python for building a simple neural network for regression and I would like to extract the weights and the bias in order to use them in another program. Can somebody maybe point out how to extract the weights from the tf neural network and compute the prediction from the same weights, with simple matrix multiplication and addition once the tensorflow NN is trained. Also will this  computation improve the prediction time(since tf.predict does some additional computations)?

Comment: this was what I could find relevant to your query - https://github.com/google/prettytensor/issues/6

Comment: My guess is that it's not likely to improve prediction time, substantially at least. Numpy might get you there, but may not be worth it. Not sure about the inner workings of `tf.predict`, I've only been working with Keras.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tf.train.Saver` class to save your model as a ckpt file and use it later:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
 with tf.Session() as sess:
    #your code here
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "/model_path/model.ckpt")
```

To restore the variables:

```
saver.restore(sess, "/your_path/model.ckpt")
```

Complete documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model

Comment: Could you maybe also elaborate how to use the weights saved to compute the prediction, with simple matrix multiplication, without loading them again into a tf Graph?